# Any Hidden Field in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, screen, hidden, kivymd

KivyMD Programmers...

like  in html... any Hidden field in KivyMD ?

**acutally i wants to hide MDLabel or MDTextField's id's value**

```
<ScreenSearchResult>:
    name: 'Screen_Search_Result'
    orientation: 'vertical'       
       
    MDLabel:
        id:args_str_id
        **#here i wants "args_str_id" as a hidden**
```

.py

```
def on_start(self):
    URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/Results/notices/"            
                
    url_data    =   requests.get(url = URL)          
    data        =   url_data.json()        
    json_str    =   json.dumps(data)
    resp        =   json.loads(json_str)
    
    # for i in range(50):
    for i in resp:
        # item = OneLineListItem(text='Item ' + str(i))            
        item = OneLineListItem(text=f'Result {i["AnnResultCode"]}, {i["MonthCode"]} {i["SessionCode"]}',
        on_release=lambda x, value_for_pass=i["ID"]: self.passValue(value_for_pass)            
        )                        

        # Add All Items on Screen_School_Results
        self.help_str.get_screen('Screen_School_Results').ids.list.add_widget(item)
        
                
def passValue(self, *args): 
    args_str = ','.join(map(str,args))
            
    URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/Results/viewResultPageAPI/"+args_str+"/"            
                
    url_data    =   requests.get(url = URL) 
    if url_data:            
        
        data        =   url_data.json()        
        json_str    =   json.dumps(data)
        resp        =   json.loads(json_str)                

        result_screen  =   self.help_str.get_screen('Screen_Search_Result')
        result_screen.manager.current = 'Screen_Search_Result'
        result_screen.ids.lbl_search_result.text = f'Result {resp["AnnResultCode"]} {resp["MonthCode"]} {resp["SessionCode"]}'
        result_screen.ids.args_str_id.text = args_str

        result_screen.ids.args_str_id.remove_widget(args_str)

    else:
        toast('Record Not Found!')
        result_screen  =   self.help_str.get_screen('Screen_Search_Result')
        result_screen.manager.current = 'Screen_Search_Result'
        result_screen.ids.lbl_search_result.text = "Result Nothing Found!"
```

**#i wants to use args_str value but don't wants to show on screen**

**result_screen.ids.args_str_id.text = args_str**

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. The value of an `id` is not displayed anyway. Please clarify your question.

Comment: John Anderson : Can we use Hidden Field in KivyMD ?